# Error while creating bean: Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

Searching for a few days for the right answer but no luck. Please help.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminContactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.dao.ContactDao nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.controller.admin.AdminContactController.contactDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CrossfithoornPU' is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
    <!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation.
    Scan a package for "targets" to work on. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.controller"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.daoImpl"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.model"/>

    <!-- Selects a static view for rendering without the need for an explicit controller / sets a default page when app is  -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>

    <!--???-->
    <bean id="applicationConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean"
          p:registerDefaultFormatters="true" />

    <!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods
    Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all @Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService" />

    <!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!--    Add Transaction support -->
    <bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="emf" />
    <!--    <bean id="txTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" value="myTxManager" />
    </bean>-->
    <!--    Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crossfithoorn"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="nbuser"/>
    </bean>

    <!--    Add JPA support--> 
    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnit">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--    View resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>  
    </bean>   
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn</groupId>
    <artifactId>CrossFitHoorn</artifactId>
    <version>crossfithoorn</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>CrossFitHoorn</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <querydsl.version>3.5.1</querydsl.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring_security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring_security.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL JDBC connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate JPA Provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>                     <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>     
        <!-- C3P0-based implementation of the Hibernate ConnectionProvider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.GA</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>  
        <!-- Logging dependencies  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>                                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**ContactDaoImpl using query-dsl**

```
    @Service
public class ContactDaoImpl extends ServiceImpl<Contact> implements ContactDao {

    private final QContact qContact = QContact.contact;

    public ContactDaoImpl() {
        super(Contact.class, QContact.contact);
    }

    // inject database connection
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        return from(qContact).distinct().list(qContact);
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getById(Integer id) {
        return em.find(Contact.class, id);
    }
```

**AdminContactController**

```
@Controller
public class AdminContactController {

    @Autowired ContactDao contactDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/contact/list", method = GET)
    public String adminContactPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("contacts", contactDao.getAllContacts());

        return "/admin/contact/lijst";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/contact/view", method = GET)
    public String viewContact() {
        return "/admin/contact/view";
    }
```

**ServiceImpl**

```
public class ServiceImpl<T extends Object> implements Service<T> {

    public static final QContact qCcontact = QContact.contact;
    public static final QUser qUser = QUser.user;
    public static final QWod qWod = QWod.wod;
    public static final QWodWinkel qWodWinkel = QWodWinkel.wodWinkel;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CrossfithoornPU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    protected final Class<T> entClass;
    protected final EntityPathBase<T> entity;

    public ServiceImpl(Class<T> entClass, EntityPathBase entity) {
        this.entClass = entClass;
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public Class<T> getEntClass() {
        return entClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T getById(Integer id) {
        T foundEntity = em.find(entClass, id);
        if (foundEntity == null) {
            try {
                throw new ObjectRetrievalFailureException(entClass, id);
            } catch (ObjectRetrievalFailureException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return foundEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return from().list(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteObj(T obj) {
        em.remove(obj);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        T foundEntity = getById(id);
        em.remove(foundEntity);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public T merge(T obj) {
        return em.merge(obj);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void persist(T obj) {
        em.persist(obj);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void persistAll(Collection<T> objs) {
        for (T obj : objs) {
            em.persist(obj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh(T obj) {
        em.refresh(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        em.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void detach(T obj) {
        em.detach(obj);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new JPAQuery object associated with the default EntityManager
     *
     */
    protected JPAQuery query() {
        return new JPAQuery(em);
    }

    public JPAQuery from() {
        return from(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public JPAQuery from(EntityPath<?> from) {
        return query().from(from);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the log, its clear. Look:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.dao.ContactDao nl.crossfit.crossfithoorn.controller.admin.AdminContactController.contactDao;
```

Well, here we see that `AdminContactController` needs an instance of `ContactDao`.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed;
```

And here, the log show us that **Injection of persistence dependencies failed**.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CrossfithoornPU' is defined
```

In your application context, you set `persistenceUnit`:

```
<!-- Add JPA support --> 
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnit">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring [uses the specified persistence unit name as the name of the default persistence unit, if applicable and only applied if no external PersistenceUnitManager specified](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPersistenceUnitName-java.lang.String-)

The error is due the persistence unit name. How about taking a look at `persistence.xml`? If you need, update your question with your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: thanks a lot Bruno. I wasn't paying any attention to the ServiceImpl interface. It's also obvious in that interface: @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CrossfithoornPU")
    protected EntityManager em;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have 2 entityManager: in the ContactDaoImpl and ServiceImpl. You can leave only the 2nd one. The second, exception says "no bean named CrossfithoomPU" is definied. Change this name to "persistenceUnit" as it's in your xml file.